# Measuring throughput of responses using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

For my university project, I need to calculate and plot the throughput for a given log file.
What I have is a csv file, with two rows for each of the requests: one with a timestep of sending the request and one with a timestep of receiving the response. Here are some examples:

```
date,time,phase,processName,action,queryID,typeOfQuery,latency
03/02/2022,14:58:38.733863,Benchmark,Process27,SendingQuery,857
03/02/2022,14:58:38.742730,Benchmark,Process27,ReceivedResponse,857,BasicQuery,8847
...
03/02/2022,14:59:39.278393,Benchmark,Process44,SendingQuery,550
03/02/2022,14:59:39.293449,Benchmark,Process44,ReceivedResponse,550,NextPage,15041
```

I would like to receive a plot, where each ***second*** of the throughput is measured and plotted. I'm not sure whether I should calculate for each second how many requests have been answered or how many requests have been sent but not answered (are worked on during that second). In other words, I would like to have a plot with each second plotted with its corresponding throughput.
For data analysis, I'm using Python and Pandas library, and here is what I have tried already:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
DATA_PATH = <path_to_the_data>
df: pd.DataFrame = pd.read_csv(DATA_PATH)
df_responses = df[df.action == "ReceivedResponse"]
print(df_responses.head(10))
df_responses.resample("S")
df_responses.plot()
```

Comment: Could you add what your expected output would be for that data to the question?

Comment: @MartinEvans that is a part of this problem, I don't know tbh. I need to calculate the throughput and plot it. For the plot the best way would be a line plot I think.